# heroku/php request not found on server

Tags: php, url, heroku

I created MVC construction with php. It takes url, `then trim($url, '/')`, 
and depending on my routes, controller works. It works perfectly on my localhost. i deployed it to heroku. When i go root route "/", heroku gives me page, but when i go '/login', heroku sends following error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

What can it be?

i tried to search other questions, but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```